# "onchange" event not firing in Safari family browsers(for a fieldset)

Tags: google-chrome, safari, onclick, onchange, fieldset

I know that I should use its alternative "onclick" for "checkboxes", to overcome this problem in "Safari" and "Chrome". But what should I do if I want to use an "onchange" *event* for a "fieldset" (a group of checkboxes)?

Comment: I would very much like to know the answer to this..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that assigning "onchange" *event* after page load using "javascript" , works! Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


      window.onload = function() {

            var fieldsets = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset");
            for( i = 0 ; i < fieldsets.length ; i++ ) {

                  fieldsets[i].onchange = function() {

                         Validate(); // Calling sample function
                  }
            }

      }



      function Validate() {

            // Sample function content

      }


</script>
```