# Javascript On change event is not firing in Safari after selecting the dropdown value

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

I have a dropdown in my page. Whenever a user is selected the option it should open a new window with the selected index url. The below code is working in all browsers except Safari.

Any idea to solve this issue?

```
<form>
    <select class="searchboxproduct" style="width: 243px;" name="URL"  onchange="window.open(this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value)">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="www.gmail.com/">Gmail</option>
        <option value="www.google.com">google</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Hava a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598120/onchange-event-not-firing-in-safari-family-browsersfor-a-fieldset

Comment: can you please provide the code..

Comment: that code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code, it didn't open a new tab, either.
But when I set the safari settings to **NOT block pop-up windows**, it worked !
Therefore I don't think it's your code's problem.
[image]

larger size of picture is [here](http://www.ncc.edu/programsandcourses/distance_ed_online/disable_popup_blocking.shtml)

Comment: Hi thanks. Yes its working. But how to uncheck that option in code because we cant inform the user to uncheck that option. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @user2899686 I've no idea how to fix it, either. Maybe you should try another way of doing this, for example, a `a` with `_blank`; or add a button, new page shows when people select some item and click it  :)

Comment: my boss dont want GO button. Thats the problem.